# Get scrollbar position wxWebView

Tags: c++, webview, scrollbar, wxwidgets

The title says it all. Get the vertical scrollbar position from a wxWebView since wxWebView::GetScrollPos doesn't work (It always returns 0).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The idea is to run JavaScript code to get the scrollbar position into a variable named "output", since wxWidgets provides facilities to get the output of a chunk of JavaScript code (Unlike WebKitGTK).

The code looks like this:

```
wxString output;
//Note that you can use the document.body.scrollLeft to get the horizontal scroll
wxString get_document_text_script = "document.body.scrollTop";
if(!webview->RunScript(get_document_text_script, &output))
{
    output = "0"; //Safeguard against errors or half-loaded pages
}
```